# Application needs no interruption at all

Tags: android, android-notifications

I write an android app for athletic examinations in my corporation.

Specifically, in one mile run examination, examiner person needs no interruptions at all, because he will loose 400m checkpoint passes of examinees.

No phone calls, SMS, messages, alarms, calendar notifications, nothing, nothing, nothing.

Until now, I think the easy way: a dialog which informs examiner to go to flight mode. It doesn't cover all these interruptions, but it is the best solution so far.

Is something better out there?

Comment: Turn their phone off?

Answer (score 1):

That kind of interruption is simply unavoidable and out of your app reach. Android system receive and emit all kind of interruptions (events) from notification to low battery. Every event has its own app which respond events using intent-filter, broadcast listener, etc. so you can't really have access to all apps that wasn't yours.

Simply put, no you can't. Your Airplane mode solution + No disruption mode might be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use the [Android Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) feature.